# Trying to print the second largest number in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
x = input()
y = map(int, input().split())
score = list(y)
score2 = score.remove(max(score))
print(max(score2))
```

When I execute the above code with inputs x = 4 and y = 1 2 3 4, it shows an error message 'NoneType value is not iterable'. The last but previous line 'score2 = score.remove(max(score))' returns a None value. Why does this happen? I intend to create code which fetches the second largest number in the list

Comment: If y = 1 2 3 3, should it return 2 or 3?

Comment: Voting to close as Unclear due to @Acccumulation's comment. Cover your edge cases in these questions, please. Empty list would be another one.

Answer (score 2):

Method `remove()` from `list` doesn't return anything. It changes list inplace. So your `score2` value will be always `None`.

The corrected program should look like (with few cosmetic corrections, will work for input of 2 values and higher):

```
score = sorted(map(int, input().split()))[-2]
print(score)
```

Comment: You can also do `sorted(map(int, input().split()),reverse =True)[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do -

```
y=[1, 2, 3, 4]
max_num = max(y)
print(max(num for num in y if num!=max_num))
```

Comment: This is highly inefficient. You are doing one pass over array for finding max_num. For num for num in y if num!=max_num you are creating another array(so that consumes memory) and then you are finding max from this array which is another pass

Comment: When you sort the list and return the second value as stated above if you pass a list that has two of the highest number (i.e. y=[1, 2, 4, 4]) you are still going to return the highest value.